# Putting the output of a command with interaction inside a variable while using grep in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, freebsd

This program I use has it's own variables to set when you run it, so I want to set those variables and then greping the output then storing it inside a variable. However, I don't know how to go about this the correct way. The idea I have doesn't work. The focus is on lines 7 through 14.

```
1  #!/usr/local/bin/bash
2  source /home/gempak/NAWIPS/Gemenviron.profile
3  FILENAME="$(date -u '+%Y%m%d')_sao.gem"
4  SFFILE="$GEMDATA/surface/$FILENAME"
5  echo -n "Enter the station ID: "
6  read -e STATION
7  OUTPUT=$(sflist << EOF
8  SFFILE = $SFFILE
9  AREA = @$STATION
10 DATTIM = all
11 SFPARM = TMPF;DWPF
12 run
13 exit
14 EOF)
15 echo $OUTPUT
```

But I get this:

```
./listweather: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./listweather: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Can you please explain more what exactly is the problem and where is it in the script?

Comment: Sure. The problem lies in lines 7 through 14. I'm trying to grep the output of this command by the STATION variable, and then sending the output from grep into another variable then printing it. The thing is that this sflist program requires interaction as well.

Comment: Actually no. On what lines would I put these on?

Comment: Ok, so you have a program sflist that needs to take inputs and generates an output which you want to filter for the $STATION variable data. But, if that is so, the pipe looks wrong. The sflist should be invoked and its output passed to the pipe towards grep. Your line 7 tries to send the grep output towards sflist.

Comment: Oh, and the stuff between lines 8 - 13 is the input I'm trying to give to the program, they're not command arguments.

Comment: Ok, I took grep out, and I still got this:

line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: How about catching your sflist output into a variable TEMPOUT and then running the grep on that for STATION? That should keep the script simple. Don't try to do too many things together.

Comment: Right, I took out grep with process of elimination, but I still got this anyways, so I can't even get the output yet: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)' line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: That's very curious. The error you describe should occur only when the closing parenthesis, ')' you show on line 14 is missing.

Comment: I had to give ) it's own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together everyone's answers, I came across a working solution myself. This code works for me:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
source /home/gempak/NAWIPS/Gemenviron.profile
FILENAME="$(date -u '+%Y%m%d')_sao.gem"
SFFILE="$GEMDATA/surface/$FILENAME"
echo -n "Enter the station ID: "
read -e STATION

OUTPUT=$(sflist << EOF
SFFILE = $SFFILE
AREA = @$STATION
DATTIM = ALL
SFPARM = TMPF;DWPF
run
exit
EOF
)
echo $OUTPUT | grep $STATION
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I'd put your program to run in a separate .sh script file, and then run the script from your first file, passing the arguments you want to pass as command line arguments. That way you can test them separately.

You could also do it in a function, but I like the modularity of the second script. I don't udnerstand exactly what you are trying to do above, but something like:

```
runsflist.sh:
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="$(date -u '+%Y%m%d')_sao.gem"
SFFILE="$GEMDATA/surface/$FILENAME"
AREA = @$STATION
DATTIM = all
SFPARM = TMPF;DWPF
grep $STATION | sflist

main.sh:
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter the station ID: "
read -e STATION
OUTPUT=`runsflist.sh`
echo $OUTPUT
```

Comment: The AREA, DATTIM, and SFPARM variables are COMPLETELY separate from bash, it's the programs own variables I have to set when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

If sflist needs interaction, I'd try something like this:

```
SFFILE=$(
  ( echo SFFILE = "$SFFILE"
    echo AREA = "@$STATION"
    echo DATTIM = all
    echo SFPARM = TMPF;DWPF
    echo run
    cat
  ) | sflist)
```

Unfortunately, you have to type `exit` as part of the interaction.